# Get an array element data into template without using ngFor

Tags: angular, data-binding, ngfor

I want to get a particular element present in 'data' and pass it to onUpload(). How do I implement it without using ngFor?

```
<div class="uploadImage" *ngFor="let product of data; index as index">
    <label>Upload Images here</label>
    <input type="file" (change)="onUpload($event, product, index)" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg , .webp" >
</div>
```

[image: preview]

Comment: *without using ngFor*. Unrealistic, `*ngFor` is required to iterate and render each element in array.

Comment: Why don't you want to use ngFor?

Comment: @Meqwz as you can see in the image, input element is displayed multiple times. Please tell me a solution how can I use ngFor but avoiding display of repeated input elements.

Comment: @HarshSonar You only want to show the input once? If you only show it once, for example, with `ngIf="index === 0"`, how will you know what product the image is being uploaded for?